# Angular: Get ng-model by ng-attr-id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Is there a way to get `ng-model` value by `ng-attr-id` ?

I'm making a Comment/Reply box and I would like to get the value of the current reply.

Here is my html--

```
<div class="comments-list" ng-show="CommentsLoaded">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="comment in comments">
            <div>
                {{comment.content}}
            </div>
            <div ng-click="showReply(comment.id)">
                Reply
            </div>
            <div ng-class="hideReply" ng-attr-id="{{'reply-'+comment.id}}">
                <textarea ng-model="replytxt" ng-attr-id="{{'replytxt-'comment.id}}"></textarea>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" ng-click="sendReply(comment.id)">
                        Publier
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the angularjs--

```
$scope.sendReply = function(commentId){
    var elm = document.getElementById('replytxt-'+commentId);
    console.log(elm);
}
```

The above function show this in console:

```
<textarea ng-model="replytxt"  ng-attr-id="{{'replytxt-'+comment.id}}" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="replytxt-31"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve element value by its selector. Do pass `replytxt` value inside `sendReply` function itself on click.

```
ng-click="sendReply(comment.id, replytxt)"

$scope.sendReply = function(commentId, replytxt){
```

**Suggestion**: rather than having `replytxt` there independently as `ng-model`, you can put it on comment level property like `comment.replytxt`, so that you don't need to take care of passing `replytxt` value separately to server.

```
ng-click="sendReply(comment)"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.sendReply = function(comment){
    console.log(comment.id, comment.replytxt);
}
```

Comment: Works great. Your suggestion is better than mine. Thank you so much

Comment: @AmadouBeye Glad to know that, Thanks ;)